# Javascript combat turn system

Tags: javascript

I will try to be as clear as possible but I may miss information. If you need more information to answer feel free to ask.

My combat is a function which is called each time I click on a specific button

Here are the logs :

```
var clochardInitiative = 9;
var Initiative = 10;

var fightClochard = function()
{
    if (clochardInitiative>Initiative)
    {
        HPNow-=(clochardDmg-Armor);
        clochardLifeNow -= (Dmg-clochardArmor);
        updateStats();
    }

    else if (Initiative>=clochardInitiative)
    {
        clochardLifeNow -= (Dmg-clochardArmor);
        HPNow-=(clochardDmg-Armor)
        updateStats();
    }   
}
```

I would like that the fighter which has the higher value of Initiative attacks first. And if he kills is opponents. Then the opponent cannot attack.

Right now with this code both are attacking even if one of them just died before.

Thank you :)

Comment: I don't see any test that a player is still alive. Anyway I highly suggest to not differ between the players by adding a prefix to the names but create different object: e.g. `player.initiative`  and  `clochard.initiative`. Especially different naming like `HPNow`, `clochardLifeNow` which obviously represents the same thing should have the same naming.

Comment: I don't see much difference between the code in each if-statement. They seem to be doing the same thing. Changing the order is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much wrong with your code. Basically your code should look like this:

```
var Fighter = function (life, armor, initiative, dmg) {
  this.life = life;
  this.armor = armor;
  this.initiative = initiative;
  this.dmg = dmg;
};

Fighter.prototype.fight = function(opponent) {
  if (opponent.initiative>this.initiative)
  {
      this.life-=(opponent.dmg-this.armor);
      if(this.life<=0) {
         updateStats();
         return; // <- ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION
      }
      opponent.life-=(this.dmg-opponent.armor);
      updateStats();
   }
   else if (this.initiative>=opponent.initiative)
   {
     opponent.life-=(this.dmg-opponent.armor);
     if(opponent.life<=0) {
         updateStats();
         return; // <- ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION
     }
     this.life-=(opponent.dmg-this.armor);
     updateStats();
   }  
};
```

But I would strongly recommend to have a look at guides and documentation on "Object Oriented Javascript" before you continue, e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: thank you. I am starting to clean my code and I will follow your advices :-)

Answer (score -1):

First off in both methods you are decreasing both parties lives! Efectivily it means it costs you life to hit.

```
var fightClochard = function()
{
    if (clochardInitiative>Initiative)
    {
        HPNow-=(clochardDmg-Armor);
        //clochardLifeNow -= (Dmg-clochardArmor); <-- commented out because the clochard has hit 
        updateStats();
    }

    else if (Initiative>=clochardInitiative)
    {
        clochardLifeNow -= (Dmg-clochardArmor);
        //HPNow-=(clochardDmg-Armor) <-- commented out because player has hit the clochard.
        updateStats();
    }   
}
```